# acrord32 CLOSE immediately after print

Tags: batch-file, acrobat

Need to **Close** acrord32.exe immediatly after the print command is executed please help

```
@echo off
rem start "" "acrord32" "xxxxxx.pdf"
acrord32/N/T xxxxxx.pdf
taskkill /f /im AcroRd32.exe
```

currently the acrobat reader windows needs to be closed manually
Acrobat Reader ver XI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoIt` would be a good way to press the print button, and close it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll find somebody to ask this question. So I will answer.

As I know, Acrobat Reader DC does not support automatic shutdown.

So what I thought was to use WMI to look up a list of print jobs.

The following article is written in C #.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6592/A-Simple-Approach-for-Controlling-Print-Jobs-using

Through the above link, I inquired the list of the printer queue and implemented it so that the program can be terminated after the printer queue is terminated.

I hope my answers help everyone.